# Disable shortcut of translation in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

Is it possible to disable <kbd>right click</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>, the shortcut for translation? Or is it possible to totally disable the Chrome translation function?

Comment: If you want to disable the Translation bar, see [here](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=173424).

Comment: thanks for your reply. I want disable the hot key of translation. It would also be OK if the whole function of translation is disabled.

Comment: I guess there's nothing new here since 2013? I'd really like to remove the translate context menu option to prevent sensitive information being sent to Google Translate by accident. The toolbar can be disabled in HTML meta-tags, but this doesn't affect the context menu.

Answer (score 2):

There are Chrome extensions that can add options to the context menus, I've haven't seen ones that remove options (as it's not widely requested).

You could write your own extension that just uses the chrome.ContextMenus API [remove method](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contextMenus.html#method-remove). The method takes an integer or string, so you may have to guess at the title of the Translate option. You could also look at the [Chromium source code](http://dev.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/get-the-code) which I'm sure is similar to Chrome's source and find the title or id there.

You can disable the translate function, but **this will not disable the mouse shortcut**. From the chrome help:

> Right-click any page and select Translate to English, even if you disable the translation bar for a site or language.